# Angular 6: use a service to get local json data

Tags: json, angular

I have a movies.json that contain a list of movies and I want to create a MoviesServices to get the data where I want.

My MoviesServices:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class MoviesService {

  movies: string[];

  constructor(private httpService: HttpClient) {
    this.getMovies();
  }

  getMovies() {
    this.httpService.get('../../assets/movies.json').subscribe(
      data => {
        this.movies = data as string[];
        console.log(this.movies); // My objects array
      },
      (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        console.log(err.message);
      }
    );
    console.log(this.movies); // Undefined
  }

}
```

Firstly, I have no idea why the first **console.log()** works and the second not, can you tell me why ?

Here is my component where I need to get the data:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MoviesService } from '../services/movies/movies.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-movies',
  templateUrl: './movies.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./movies.component.css']
})

export class MoviesComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'films-synopsys';
  movies;

  constructor(private myService: MoviesService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.myService.movies); // Undefined
  }
}
```

Of course this is not working. Can you tell me how must I do ? I'm newbie angular

Comment: `console.log(this.movies); // Undefined` fails because AJAX requests are _asynchronous_ - this line has executed _before_ your AJAX request has completed, and therefore _before_ the callback code which populates the `movies` variable (from the AJAX response) has executed. If you want to use this data for something, then you must wait for the AJAX call to return before you try to use it.

Comment: How must I do for waiting AJAX request completed ? I see only examples for AngularJS in google

Comment: @Delboar you're already doing it with your ".subscribe" method...anything you want to do with the data must happen after this method runs.

Comment: @Delboar, please consider marking the answer that helped you fix your issue as a solution to point the readers right to it and to end the loop.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So basically you need to return an `Observable` from your service and then `subscribe` to it from your Component. You can then assign your `response` to the Component property `movies`

Try this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class MoviesService {

  constructor(private httpService: HttpClient) { }

  getMovies() {
    return this.httpService.get('../../assets/movies.json');
  }

}
```

And in your Component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MoviesService } from './movies.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  title = 'films-synopsys';
  movies;

  constructor(private myService: MoviesService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myService.getMovies()
      .subscribe(res => this.movies = res);
  }
}
```

Here's a [**Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-movie-read-load-json-sample-eg?file=src/app/movies.service.ts) for your ref.

Comment: Not working. I can use RES only IN THE FUNCTION. I want to put ALL THE DATA in movies variable.

Comment: nice, but it would be much better with a proper explanation of what's happening, and why...

Comment: No, everytime this.movies stay empty

Answer (score 2):

Change your method to return an Observable which you can subscribe to:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
...
getMovies(): Observable<string []> {
    this.httpService.get('../../assets/movies.json').subscribe(
      data => {
        this.movies = data as string[];
        return this.movies;
      },
      (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        console.log(err.message);
      }
    );
  }
```

In your calling code:

```
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';

this.myService.getMovies().subscribe(movies => {
  console.log(movies); // My objects array
}
```

Comment: Is there anything else to add ? I'm getting error: ERROR TypeError: "this.myService.getMovies(...) is undefined" > It look like he don't recognize subscribe() method

Answer (score 1):

The reason the first console log works is because you are doing it within an observable's subscription. Subscriptions have three states, `Next`, `Error`, `Complete` and so when you console log the first time, within the subscription `next` state you get the value that was pushed out from the event stream.

In your component the reason why it doesn't work is due to the fact that observables are lazy, and that you need to initialize the data by calling `this.myService.getMovies()` first to make the subscription happen.

A better way to do this would been to pass observables around and use `async` pipe in the html template.